# 4k display and intel CPU with integrated graphics that should support 4k, but settings only allow me to set 1080

Tags: display-resolution

I have a PC running Ubuntu 22.04 with a i7-4770 CPU. From what I can find, this CPU's integrated graphics should support 4k, but in the settings I am only able to set it to 1080.

What should I check to make this work? Am I missing drivers or have the wrong settings?